# .h5 file format does not close properly

Tags: python, data-formats

```py
import h5py #added
hf = h5py.File('../images.h5', 'w') #added
hf.close() #added

h5_file = tables.open_file("images.h5", mode="w")
```

I also tried:

```py
h5py.File.close(hf)
```

the error that pops up in both cases is:

```
ValueError: The file 'restricted_images.h5' is already opened.  Please close it before reopening in write mode.
```

I've also tried:

```py
if isinstance(obj, h5py.File):   # Just HDF5 files
    obj.close()
```

while

```py
In[]: hf
Out[]: <Closed HDF5 file>
```

, the file is not closed yet.

Comment: I think the question is best suited for StackOverflow

Comment: as you may have noticed, the outcome is indicating that it's a closed object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use something like the following snippet:

```
with h5py.File("some_path.h5") as f:
   f["data1"] = some_data

import h5py #added
with h5py.File('../images.h5', 'w') as f:    
    h5_file = tables.open_file("images.h5", mode="w")
    # do what ever you want to do, it will be closed by itself.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but it doesn't also work.

Comment: You meant it did not close the file? Consider that outside of the *with* the file is going to be closed. In your code snippet, it is also denoting that it's been closed already.

Comment: Based on the error, the problem was with opening an already opened file. Actually, I shouldn't create the images.h5 file myself. Thank you so much for your time. This `with` thing is really useful by the way.